# codeigniter convert html page into pdf and send mail using Html2pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3

i have one issue with html2pdf library in doceigniter. i am trying to send view page as pdf in mail using Html2pdf library but i cant able to implement this library in codeigniter

this is my controller code

```
$this->load->library('Html2pdf');

    //Set folder to save PDF to
    $this->Html2pdf->folder('./assets/');

    //Set the filename to save/download as
    $this->Html2pdf->filename('test.pdf');

    //Set the paper defaults
    $this->Html2pdf->paper('a4', 'portrait');

    $data = array(
        'title' => 'PDF Created',
        'message' => 'Hello World!'
    );

    //Load html view
    $this->Html2pdf->html($this->load->view('pdf', $data, true));

    if($this->Html2pdf->create('save')) {
        //PDF was successfully saved or downloaded
        // echo 'PDF saved';
    }
```

when i run this code i get this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined property: Example::$Html2pdf
>   Filename: controllers/Example.php
>   Line Number: 15
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function folder() on a non-object

please help me for implement this library 
thanks everyone

Comment: Try using lower cases i.e. `$this->load->library('html2pdf');$this->html2pdf->folder('./assets/');`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below mentioned solution

```
//Load the library
$this->load->library('html2pdf');

//Set folder to save PDF to
$this->html2pdf->folder('./uploads/pdfs/');

//Set the filename to save/download as
$this->html2pdf->filename('new.pdf');

//Set the paper defaults
$this->html2pdf->paper('a4', 'portrait');
```

for Sending this particular file in email.

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email PDF Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email a freshly created PDF');   

$this->email->attach($path_to_pdf_file);

$this->email->send();
```

Let me know if it not work.

Comment: I have tried it with CI2 and CI3. Its working perfect with CI2, I am currently working on CI3 library in which I am getting error. So once it will finalized than available on github.

Comment: thanks for replay once you are get success then send me link here of github

Comment: Please find updated code for codeigniter 3 on Github repo. https://github.com/shyamshingadiya/HTML2PDF-CI3